# Cannot browserify materialize-css npm module

Tags: npm, gulp, browserify

I am new to materialize css framework. I am using laravel-elixir 4.0.0 with gulp to browserify the installed npm materialize-css module.

Here are my configurations

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "materialize-css": "^0.97.5"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp   = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | ELIXIR ASSET MANAGEMENT
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

elixir.config.sourcemaps = true;

// Set the path for compiled assets
var build_path = "public/compiled/";

elixir(function(mix) {

    /*
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Javascript browserification
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    mix.browserify(
        "app.js",
        build_path + "app.js"
    );
});
```

**app.js**

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
require('materialize-css');
```

However, when I run gulp command it returns the following errors:-

> gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Browserify Failed!: Cannot find module
>   'jQuery' from
>   '/var/www/laravel5/node_modules/materialize-css/bin'

**My node versions:-**
node v5.6.0, npm v3.6.0

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: I'm not using Elixir. Only Gulp, browserify and materialize-css.

This is what I have in my project using `materialize-css`:

- in the `package.json` I have added to the `devDependencies` list `browserify-shim`, and configured it:

  ```
  "dependencies":{
     "materialize-css": "xx.yy.zz",
     "jquery": "xx.yy.zz",
     ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "xx.yy.zz"
    "browserify-shim": "xx.yy.zz"
    ...
  },
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "materialize": "./node_modules/materialize-css/bin/materialize.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "materialize": "materialize"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  ...
  ```
- in the `app.js` file I'm then importing jQuery and `materialize` as usual:

  ```
  var $ = require('jquery');
  require('materialize');
  ```

Then just used the regular recipe for `gulp` and `browserify` to build them.